# Are we allowed to save the access token from Facebook OAuth?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are we allowed to save the access token from Facebook [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)?

Is it legal? I'm just asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to store the access token somewhere on your server, so that you don't have to ask the user to authenticate every time you need to use Facebook's API on the user's behalf.  Note that the access token expires, so you'll only want to store this temporarily.

Comment: i have add a offline access permission ... so there is no expired date , right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using the offline access permission, so I'm not familiar with it and I can't really comment on it.